# Unable to find provider "Images" with locale "en_US" fzaninotto/Faker when seeding

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to seed my database using `fzaninotto/Faker` but when I run `php artisan db:seed` I get the following error.

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Unable to find provider "Images" with locale "en_US"
>
> db:seed [--class[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force]

I have three seeder classes that should be executed and neither has any reference to "Images" (no table nor fields named Images). This is the code I have on `DatabaseSeeder`

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    protected $tables = [
        'users','posts','feedbacks'
    ];
    protected $seeders = [
        'UsersTableSeeder',
        'PostsTableSeeder',
        'FeedbacksTableSeeder'
    ];
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();

        $this->cleanDatabase();
        foreach ($this->seeders as $seedClass)
        {
            $this->call($seedClass);
        }

    }

    private function cleanDatabase()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
        foreach ($this->tables as $table)
        {
            DB::table($table)->truncate();

        }
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
    }
}
```

Seeder Classes:

```
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Bicicletas\Feedbacks\Feedback;
use Bicicletas\Users\User;

class FeedbacksTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();
        $usersIds = User::lists('id');
        $stars = array(1,2,3,4,5);

        foreach(range(1, 10) as $index)
        {
            Feedback::create([
                'user_id' => $faker->randomElement($usersIds, $count=1),
                'rating'  => $faker->randomElement($stars),
                'content' =>$faker->text($maxNbChars = 150),
                'created_at' =>$faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '-1 years', $endDate = 'now')

            ]);
        }
    }

}

use Bicicletas\Posts\Post;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class PostsTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        foreach(range(1, 20) as $index)
        {
            Post::create([

            'title' => $faker->text($maxNbChars = 50),
            'slug'  =>   $faker->slug,
            'content' =>$faker->text($maxNbChars = 550),
            'created_at'=>$faker->dateTime()
            ]);
        }
    }
}


use Bicicletas\Users\User;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        foreach(range(1, 20) as $index)
        {
            User::create([
                'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
                'lastname' =>$faker->lastName,
                'country' =>$faker->country,
                'email' =>$faker->email,
                'avatar'=>"$index.jpg",
                'password' =>'secreto'
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried this before and it worked. Can you shed some light on this error?

Comment: Have a look on `app\config\app.php` and search for the key `providers`. Do you have any named "Images"? Also, edit your question and add the contents of each Seeder class. Finally, execute a `composer dumpautoload` and check if it solves anything.

Comment: Hello @milz Thank you for helping me, I have the reflection provider in app.php, but the question is Why is this error comming out if no image service provider is involved in seeding these classes?   'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider', and in Fakades I have   'Images'            => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image',

Comment: I have renamed the  'Images'  => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' for  'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' and then autoload, but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error is being throwed when seeding not because it has "something to do" with seeds but because Laravel executes it's bootstrap when seeding and you have an issue with that package.

If you've followed [the official guide](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel) you need to add the following things in `config/app.php`:

- Add to the `$providers`

  ```
  'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
  ```
- Add the `$alias`

  ```
  'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
  ```

Since you've already done that (per your comments), you are probably need to publish the package's configuration:

```
$ php artisan config:publish intervention/image
```

There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/125) with users that have that issue. Some of them resolved it with `composer dumpautoload` and others have issues because they have models called `Image`. So, if this didn't solve your question, take a look at the issue, it might be helpful.

Comment: Let me tell you that I have a Folder  app\Bicicletas\Images, which have just  renamed to Photos and see what happens, Now the error is "[InvalidArgumentException]
Unable to find provider "Photos" with locale "en_US"

db:seed [--class[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force]" . Another thing is when I tried to execute php artisan config:publish intervention/image

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Configuration not found.

config:publish [--path[="..."]] [--force] package

Comment: I have deleted that directory and still getting the same error. also dumpautoload previous